# CentOS Stream 8 Ansible 2.9.23 How to install winrm and credssp modules

Tags: ansible, centos, winrm, centos8, credssp

We use WinRm with CredSSP to connect Windows servers. I am setting up the new server `CentOS Stream 8`

Based on the document if I install `pip3 install pywinrmcredssp` this command its not finding this module.

```
pip3 install pywinrmcredssp
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Collecting pywinrmcredssp
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywinrmcredssp (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywinrmcredssp
```

How to install this ansible module globally in CentOS Steam 8?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the [ansible page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#installing-credssp-library) and the [package page](https://pypi.org/project/pywinrm/) both list the package name as `pywinrm[credssp]` instead pf `pywinrmcredssp`.

Comment: `pip3` is not finding this module also `pywinrmcredssp` giving this message: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywinrmcredssp (from versions: )`

Comment: The module has the square brackets included. I am able to `pip3 install pywinrm[credssp]` on my machine.

Comment: I have to install this first `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall`, then pip3 installed worked. `pip3 install pywinrm requests-ntlm requests requests-credssp`